# Why do websites insist that credit card numbers are entered as a single 16 digit number?

Tags: credit-card, websites

My bank cards all have a 16 digit card number on the front, written as 4 blocks of 4 digits, for example:

```
1234 5678 9012 3456
```

Any time I enter my credit card number on a website, however, I have to do it as a single 16-digit number (e.g. `1234567890123456`), rather than typing in the 4 blocks. When I do this, I always think I've made a mistake somewhere and end up re-checking it a couple of times. It's a pain. Is there any reason why numbers have to be entered as a single 16-digit number? Parsing 4 blocks of 4 digits would be really easy, so I assume there's a compelling reason for insisting on the single 16-digit number. I can't imagine it's anything to do with user-friendliness, so I wondered if it's some kind of security concern (although that doesn't make any sense to me). Any ideas?

Comment: First this is unrelated to security. Second: not all web sites insist that you enter the card numbers this way. This is just a usability issue, similar to requiring specifically formatted phone numbers, dates or similar.

Comment: FWIW, American Express cards are XXXX XXXXXX XXXXX (4-6-5) instead of four blocks of four.

Comment: Spaces are not significant here. The code is composed of 4*4=16 digits, so the input field is 16 digits wide. 4 fields would requires for times more work, and allowing spaces would require a larger field. This is just seen as a best effort result.

Comment: a lot of times "devs" use drop-in validation routines that wouldn't work with several inputs. It's actually relatively complicated to implement mandatory inner-dependencies on forms...

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure this has nothing to do with security. Wheater or not the credit card number is entered in one input field or many is irrelevant. Using HTTPS and storing the card number safely is the real concern with credit cards, and the design of the input field has zero impact on those.

So what is it about? Probably just developers being (rationally) lazy. Why go through the trouble of having four different fields, when you can have just one? You have to handle moving focus from one field to the next when digits are entered. Or when the user hits backspace. And what about copy paste?

So much code to write, so little time, I better go drink some coffee...

Comment: I believe the user is saying that if he adds spaces to the number the number is rejected, while he expects the application to simply ignore those spaces. Given that a credit card number contains only the digits `0-9` it's *trivial* to remove everything else from the input.

Comment: @Bakuriu Good point. That would be much less work, but still a slight annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no security consideration behind this. It's just, like this you don't have to enter tab to jump the next input field, also it's easier to handle this for the programmers too.

They could make this user friendly (like paste a space after every 4 numbers), but usually they are too lazy to do this.